# Managing SQL tables in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app which requied more than one table.

The DB is mosly for read purposes and i want to know what is the best way to manage my tables.

I tought about 2 options.

1. Create new DB class with new DB for each table.
2. Create new table in the exits DB.

What is the best for better performance in reading?

Comment: For best performance if it's really not needed dont use SqLite, maybe XML files can handle your issue ?

Comment: @SercanOzdemir you couldn't be more wrong. Try to implement a fast search through a big XML-file and you'll see.

Comment: I mean if you are just storing a few rows on SqLite dont use it. http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html

Comment: This is a nice tutorial [Sqlite Android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hat is the best for better performance in reading?

For sure don't create new database but put all tables you need in one database. Reasons are more there, for instance now you don't know whether you will need sometime in a future to create some relations between these tables.

I's not "good" to have more db files which will represent one table, it's not comfortable and efficient as well. So my suggestion to you is to keep only one db file and put all tables in this one.

The best approach to manage `SQLite` database is to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` class that wraps all required logic for reading and writing from/to database. Then, SQLiteDatabase itself provides some API methods for inserting, updating and deleting from db.

At the end as my personal recommendation. If you'll have more than one table just how i mentioned create one `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass for creating database and then for each table create object that will represent table "in objects" e.q. columns in table will become properties of object.

Finally for each table create `DAO` classes that will wrap `CRUD` operations and some specific methods for each table.

---

If you don't know how to start check these tutorials:

- [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
- [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: what is a proof of " it's not comfortable and _efficient_ as well."?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLiteDatabase`.

`SQLiteDatabase` has methods to `create`, `delete`, execute `SQL` commands, and perform other common database management tasks.

`Database names` must be `unique` within an application, not across all applications.

Read: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)